# Capturing Android applicataion traffic using FIddler

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, fiddler, httpsurlconnection

So far I managed to capture the traffic of local Java programs & Android browser successfully. However, I failed to capture traffic of my Android application (using `HttpsUrlConnection`).

While following the steps in [this](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) guide to configure the WiFi network on the device, in the step of downloading the certificate I faced an odd behavior as Chrome raised an error and Firefox installed it without opening the expected dialog:

[image: Name the certificate]

But when I try to download it again, it says that the certificate is already installed.

Anyway, when running my app (on a real device, Karbonn S203 API 19), there are no requests nor tunnels logged in Fiddler. I tried a lot including inspecting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862916/fiddler-decrypt-android-httpsurlconnection-ssl-traffic?s=1%7C1.5125) thread to no avail. In other articles I read about showing tunnels only but I don't have them either. Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I managed to install is "correctly" (with the above screen) from `Settings -> Security -> Install Certificate` after copying if from PC. Still I cannot see the requests in Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem occurred due to using some uncommon devices (well, at least uncommon in Europe/North America). They've probably made some configuration changes in their AOSP version. When working the same way with Nexus 5 I managed to add the ceritifcate under 'WiFi' and then captured requests successfully.

Comment: You saved my day! Honor 5C with 7.0 - not ok, Nexus 5 with 6.0.1 - ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app does not use Fiddler as a proxy. When you call openConnection do you pass a Proxy object to it? If so, how do you initialize this proxy object?

You might want to try sending some HTTP traffic through first to make sure you are using the correct proxy settings and then try with HTTPS.

Comment: I read that it depends on system properties `https.proxyHost` & `https.proxyPort`. I will try to implement your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: By the way, if I need to create a proxy instance, why didn't I need that when monitoring Java application on PC? I had to use only the lines above (+ the same lines for http) to make it work.